# How to timeout a running jar program in python

Tags: java, python, process

I'm using the following `Command` class to timeout a running command. It works fine with shell command, but when I use the command `java -jar` to pass it to the `Command` class to start a java program, it seems not terminating the java process. Please help.

```
class Command(object):

cmd = None
process = None
status = None
output, error = '', ''

def __init__(self, cmd):
    # if isinstance(cmd, basestring):
    #     cmd = shlex.split(cmd)
    self.cmd = cmd
    #self.process = None

def run(self, timeout, outputfile, errfile):
    def target():
        print 'Thread started'
        try:
            print self.cmd
            open(outputfile, 'w').close()
            open(errfile, 'w').close()
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True, stdout = file(outputfile, 'w+'), stderr = file(errfile, 'w+')) #
            (self.output, self.error) = self.process.communicate() #
            self.status = self.process.returncode
            print self.output #"Out:'%s'" % 
            print self.error #"Err:'%s'" % 
            print 'Thread finished'
        except:
            self.error = traceback.format_exc()
            self.status = -1      
            print self.error  

    thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
    thread.start()

    thread.join(timeout)
    if thread.is_alive():
        print 'Terminating process'
        self.process.kill() #terminate
        thread.join()
    print self.status
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Linux, more specifically, Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the shell starts a child process for java. You could either remove the `shell=True` or have your command be `exec java -jar ...`

From the man page of exec:

> The  exec()  family  of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

Comment: Thanks! the `exec` does work. But removing `shell=True` will result in errors.

Comment: Hi! Do you know the alternative of `exec` on Windows?

Comment: I don't know of a Windows option. http://serverfault.com/questions/315077/is-there-a-windows-cmd-equivalent-of-unix-shells-exec